What types of sets in the sigma algebra of generated by hitting sets?
In random set theory, a random set $X$ is a measurable mapping from a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal A, \mathbf P)$ to $(\mathbb{F}, \mathcal{F})$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is the set of closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and $\mathcal{F}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the hitting sets, $\mathbb F_K = \{F \in \mathbb F : F \cap K \neq \emptyset\}$, for compact $K\subset \mathbb R^d$.
My question concerns the events in $\mathbb{F}$, and its flexibility to contain events that we might be interested in. For example, with $B_1$ the unit ball, is $\{F \in \mathbb F : B_1 \subset F\}$ in $\mathcal F$?
The formalism I gave above is standard, and used by Chiu et al. in Stochastic Geometry, Section 6.1.2. I feel like the standard definition of a random set should be flexible enough to express $\mathbf P(B_1 \subset X)$, but I don't see how to express $B_1$ as a countable union of small, disjoint, compact $K$'s. How do I proceed if I need to express these kinds of probabilities, and summary statistics of the connected components of $X$?

Edit: I realized that if a closed set contains all rational points in $B_1$ then it must contain all of $B_1$. This seems good enough, since I can take the intersection of the hitting sets corresponding to the rational points in $B_1$.
